# React pages other then home page not working on reloading or opening pages directly in vercel deploy .all links works fine in local project.j

Tags: node.js, reactjs

This is my router

```
 <Router>
<Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route exact path="/se" element={<Home />} />
  <Route exact path="/blog" element={<Blog />} />
<Route exact path="/about" element={<About />} />
<Route exact path="/category" element={<Category />} />
<Route exact path="/product" element={<Product />} />
<Route exact path="/add-product" element={<AddProduct />} />

 </Routes>
<Footer />
        </Router>
```

i have deployed react on vercel .Everything runs smooth if i open the project from home link. on opening VERCEL_DOMAIN/category link directly is not working.my navigation links are working fine in menu.just copying the other pages link and directly open in them not working.
Tell me any way to fix this

I am expecting VERCEL_DOMAIN/anypage link to work fine on directly opening them in browser unlike opening them using link from menu.

Answer (score 1):

Make a file name vercel.json in your root folder,then add this in your vercel.json file.

```
{
  "rewrites": [{ "source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/" }]
}
```

this will solve the issue of site crashing on other routes.